# How to jump over parentheses in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I don't know how to jump over parentheses in vscode, and using arrows is really slowing me down. Does anybody know how to jump over parentheses in vscode?

And yes, I know the TabOut extension, but when I use TabOut and I press Tab, the cursor jumps to the start of the parentheses, not over them.

Comment: what does "jump over parentheses" mean?

Comment: by pressing `end` key?

Comment: Similar question, but the answers don't seem to be what you're looking for: [VS code, jump to after closing quote/braces/parenthesis](/q/36747752/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). You can [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context#editorcursornextchar) to select a different command based on the character right of the cursor, You can use **multi-command** if you need to make multiple cursor movements.

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to use multi-command to `Go to Bracket` and then arrow right once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shortcuts **go to bracket** `Ctrl+Shift+\`.

If you want, you can customize the shortcut key for this function in keyboard shortcuts(`ctrl+k ctrl+s`).

[image]

Use this shortcut key with **→** to skip brackets.